# How to add new keys and values to a json from a txt file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, txt

From a txt file with values but not keys I want to add those values to a empty json file. I have to add the key for each value, save the json file and export the json file to a new txt, this time with keys.

So I have this json file

```
{ "agenda" : []
}
```

I have this txt file (all fake data in case you wonder):

```
"Fidel","Oltra","fidel@gmail.com","6650403234"
"Merxe","Sanz","merxe@gmail.com","65345235"
"David","Garcia","dgarcia@gmail.com","69823422"
"Amparo","López","alopez@gmail.com","67234234"
"Antonio","Gómez","antoniog@gmail.com","69929292"
```

And I want the json file to look like

```
{
   "agenda":[
      {
         "Name": "Fidel",
         "Surname": "Oltra",
         "Email": "fidel@gmail.com",
         "Phone": 6650403234
      },
      {
         ...
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

I have this code that is kind of working but I don't know how to push properly the data because at the final json file doesn't look as expected.

```
const archivo = require("fs");
const json = require("fs");

const file = archivo.readFileSync('agenda.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(file);
const lines = file.split('\n');
console.log(lines);
let campos;

let rawdata = json.readFileSync('agenda.json');
let json1 = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(json1);

for (i in lines) {
    campos = lines[i].split(",");
    json1.agenda.push('Nombre:', campos[0]);
    json1.agenda.push('Apellido:', campos[1]);
    json1.agenda.push('Email:', campos[2]);
    json1.agenda.push('Teléfono:', campos[3]);
    console.log(campos);
    console.log(json1);

};

let data = JSON.stringify(json1);
json.writeFileSync('agenda2.json', data);
```

And the json when I open it is:

```
{"agenda":["Nombre:","\"Fidel\"","Apellido:","\"Oltra\"","Email:","\"fidel@gmail.com\"","Teléfono:","\"6650403234\"\r","Nombre:","\"Merxe\"","Apellido:","\"Sanz\"","Email:","\"merxe@gmail.com\"","Teléfono:","\"65345235\"\r","Nombre:","\"David\"","Apellido:","\"Garcia\"","Email:","\"dgarcia@gmail.com\"","Teléfono:","\"69823422\"\r","Nombre:","\"Amparo\"","Apellido:","\"López\"","Email:","\"alopez@gmail.com\"","Teléfono:","\"67234234\"\r","Nombre:","\"Antonio\"","Apellido:","\"Gómez\"","Email:","\"antoniog@gmail.com\"","Teléfono:","\"69929292\""]}
```

So I would like some help to make it work and learn what I am doing wrong... and also to know how to write the right final json back to txt file.

Comment: the 'fake data' it will be pasted in an input or will be recevied by a services ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand the question

Comment: im asking the data that you put in the above script ( the text file  ) will be always a text file ? never be changed ?

Comment: yes, it will be a text file

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues I found.

1. You never removed the quotes / cotizaciones from agenta.txt. This means that your ending json was escaping the quotes for you. `"String"` in JSON is `"\"String\""`.
2. In the for loop, you were pushing your keys and values into an array instead of making an object, and then pushing that object in the array.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const file = fs.readFileSync("agenda.txt", "utf8");
console.log(file);
const sinCotiz = file.replace(/"/g, ""); // remove quotes
const lines = sinCotiz.split("\n");
console.log(lines);

const rawdata = fs.readFileSync("agenda.json");
const json1 = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(json1);

for (i in lines) {
  const obj = {}; // create an object
  const campos = lines[i].split(",");
  obj["Nombre"] = campos[0]; // create keys and values for the object
  obj["Apellido"] = campos[1];
  obj["Email"] = campos[2];
  obj["Teléfono"] = campos[3];
  json1.agenda.push(obj); // push the entire object in the array
  console.log(campos);
  console.log(json1);
}

const data = JSON.stringify(json1);
fs.writeFileSync("agenda2.json", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const archivo = require("fs");
const json = require("fs");

const file = archivo.readFileSync('agenda.txt', 'utf8');

const lines = file.split('\n');

let campos;

let rawdata = json.readFileSync('agenda.json');
let json1 = JSON.parse(rawdata);

for (i in lines) {
    if(lines[i]) {
       campos = lines[i].split(",");
       let payload = {
        'Name' : campos[0].substr(1,campos[0].length-2), // to remove double quotes from the string
        'Surname' : campos[0].substr(1,campos[0].length-2),
        'Email' : campos[0].substr(1,campos[0].length-2),
        'Phone' : campos[0].substr(1,campos[0].length-2),
       }
       json1.agenda.push(payload);
     }
   };

let data = JSON.stringify(json1);
json.writeFileSync('agenda2.json', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is more simple solution,
but you can format your file as it is a CSV file . you will put a layer at first to remove the '' and change , with ; , then you will need to add a header line in your case the header will be

> Nombre;Apellido;Email;Teléfono

then you use this function :

```
function csvJSON(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }
  
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

this will gives you a formated json with the following strecture :

[{Nombre:4444,Apellido:"AAAA",....}]

and you can put the whole function directly to your agenda :)

again i think there is more simple solution , but maybe this will help.